# Mind frame rate vs craving

Tags: nirvana, mind, meditation-breath, perception

I have some hunch that when rising from the deep meditative states / jhanas, the mind becomes so slow that the world is perceived in frames. Is this true? My guess is that the speed of human brain perception is proportionate to how much craving there is, the lesser the craving the slower the mind due to disenchantment. Experienced ones please shed some light on this.

Comment: Can some Noble one calculate how much the brain perception needs to speed up to see the reality frame by frame? I have read plenty of answers that say Buddha's noting speed was super fast. Let's examine scientifically if that kind of lightning fast noting is even possible.

Comment: I mean Vipassana is just doing the noting

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is precisely what happens.  What you’ll begin to notice probably more so than the “frame” experience is that consciousness is only capable of holding one sense object at a time.  You will experience a moment of mind consciousness, eye consciousness, etc, but you’ll notice that each instance is discreet.  You never perceive eye and ear conscious at the same time, for example.

Another thing you may experience is the appearance of space between moments of consciousness.  This is extremely important for it is in these moments of cessation (yes, we’re talking nirodha here - this is different than the meditative state, however) where the potential for deeply liberating insight can occur.

**Case 99 of the Book of Serenity

Particle after Particle Samadhi**
A monk asked Yunmen, “What is particle after particle samadhi?”
Yunmen said, “Rice in the bowl, water in the pail.”

Comment: i'm not sure I understand.  are you saying something like a micro-blackout? or like some kind of buffer between mind moments?

Comment: It’s something entirely different.  It’s better described as a kind of gap.  It’s best described by what it’s not - neither mind consciousness, eye consciousness, etc.  It goes without saying that looking for nirodha is an exercise in futility (I.e. “to seek mind with the discriminating mind is the greatest of all mistakes”).  You just kinda run into it following periods of deep meditation.

Comment: @000 Thanks for the answer. Perception is a complex thing 
inside our brain. Perceptionn of time is dependent upon the observer. I mean without an observer perceiving motion, time doesn't make sense. There are animals which perceive super fast like dragon fly and then there are animals that are damn too slow. I think the way to nibbana is just slowing down the nervous system to find the leap towards cessation. I can't think any other way of cessation of phenomena. Without cessation, nibbana loses most of its value at least to me.

Comment: Time is motion. I think Buddha found the hack to change perception of things using breath meditation Anapanasati. And then he leapt into cessation. Just a guess. Otherwise cessation seems impossible.